# Show history of command in MATLAB shell

Tags: history, matlab

I used the command `matlab-shell` for opening a new MATLAB instance inside emacs. How can I have a functionality similar to the of MATLAB which allows to see at once the most recent commands and to navigate through them?
I would like to have something with the appearance of an autocomplete dialog, showing the most recent commands.